# Запретить изменение размера textarea

Tags: html, css

HTML textarea. Как убирают элемент изменения размера на **HTML** или **CSS**?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `textarea { resize: none; }`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский спасибо, надо было оформлять как ответ:)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CSS:

```
textarea {
    resize: none; /* Запрещаем изменять размер */
}
```

http://htmlbook.ru/faq/kak-zapretit-izmenenie-razmerov